# Time Series Forecasting with R: How to implement and compare ETS and ARIMA at the same time?

Tags: r, forecast

If I have a time series data and I want to do time series analysis, then which model should I choose, ETS or ARIMA?

I have searched some answers. One of them said that I should implement both ETS and ARIMA and then use test data to check the accuracy such as MAS, MSE.

However, my question is that if I implement ARIMA model, then I should stationize the raw data first because ARIMA requires stationary, but ETS does not require stationary.

In this case, is it correct to do the forecast in the following steps?

1. subset the raw data into training data and test data.
2. training data %>% ETS model, get fc1
3. stationize training data, get training_stationary
4. training_stationary %>% ARIMA model, get fc2
5. compare the accuracy of fc1 and fc2

My question is that if I do the above steps. I use different data to different model rather then use same data to different model because I implement ETS model by using training data and implement ARIMA by using training_stationary data.

I dont think it is right for time series forecast

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. One thing that I would correct is that ARIMA does not necessary require that the series should be stationary. If you are using the forecast package, the implementation can be done automatically with auto.arima function.

Comment: thanks for replying
you means that we dont have to stationize the raw time series data first. We just input the data into the auto.arima function, then the auto.arima function will do the stationize process for us automatically?

Actually, I really dont wheter know the ARIMA requires the stationary or not.
Some said ARIMA requires stationary, others said stationary is not necessary.